# Why does my program print the same line "Student #" twice?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] coursesRemTak = new int[10][2];
    java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter classes remaining and taking each term for...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < coursesRemTak.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < coursesRemTak[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("Student %d: ", i + 1);
            coursesRemTak[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            if (coursesRemTak.length >= 0 && coursesRemTak[0].length <= 21) {
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
```

For the most part, my program is running as expected, up until it starts repeating the last output twice.
Why is it doing that and how can I stop it?

Comment: Your inner loop, the `j` loop, prints `"Student %d: ", i + 1` each turn. `i` isn't changing inside the inner loop. If you print the same thing in a loop, you get repetition. What else would you expect?

Comment: probably, you need to move the `printf` code before the second loop. (you just need the `i` in the `printf`, but not `j`)

Comment: @khelwood Honestly, I'm still trying to figure this whole Java thing out. But now I know what to look out for, and more importantly, why to look out for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] coursesRemTak = new int[10][2];
    java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter classes remaining and taking each term for...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < coursesRemTak.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Student %d: ", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < coursesRemTak[i].length; j++) {
            coursesRemTak[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            if (coursesRemTak.length >= 0 && coursesRemTak[0].length <= 21) {
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
```